# ORA-00936: missing expression - hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

In hibernate when i execute `Restrictions.sqlRestriction("audit.id.revisionNum > ?",  new Long(2) ,StandardBasicTypes.LONG )`
 i'm getting

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

can anyone please tell me why i'm getting this exception
 i'm using Hibernate 3

My code is

```
Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Document.class);
criteria.createAlias("documentAudit", "audit")
.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("audit.id.revisionNum > ?",  new Long(2) ,StandardBasicTypes.LONG ));
```

Comment: audit.id.revisionNum is maybe to blame? usualy audit.id would be just an int or long. you have to provide more data to let people help you. Paste some more code about Document and id field in Document.

Comment: @goroncy you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21569601/hibernate-criteria-for-getting-details-based-on-keys-no